# Is it possible to add a mesh just by clicking in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

Is it possible to add a mesh just by clicking in the viewport ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge the fastest way to add an object with the minimum mouse movement is to press "shift" + "a"
Then select what fits you best.

[image]

Comment: thanks. The thing is that a wanna add flowers anywhere i want just by clicking on the ground

Comment: @NathanArditti it might be a good idea to mention this in the question.

Comment: @NathanArditti use your mesh (flower for exemple) as the particle of a particle system. then you can control the density with weight painting. basically it means you will be able to paint where you want the flower to be.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPenYcM6Usw